# Validar sí han pasado 5 días o más de una fecha en PHP

Tags: php, laravel, poo

Estoy programando un sistema de gestión para marmolerías y granitos.
Ando utilizando Laravel 9 y Filament PHP para realizarlo pero en este momento no es importante ese dato ya que lo que me anda trabando son cuestiones de PHP.

Escribí el siguiente código para validar si han pasado 5 días o más desde que se ha medido una mesada pero por más que simule que pasen los días siempre me devuelve el primer if.

```
$fechaMedicion = $record->size_date;
$tiemposConcluidos = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fechaMedicion. "+ 5 days"));
$result = "";
                    
    if ($fechaMedicion >= $tiemposConcluidos){
           $result = 'A tiempo';
    } elseif ($fechaMedicion < $tiemposConcluidos){
           $result = 'Urgente';
    }

 return $result;
```

Desde ya agradezco mucho la dedicación de toda la comunidad y espero una respuesta :)

Answer (score 1):

Chicos, desde ya muchisimas gracias por su tiempo.

Ninguna de los dos códigos anteriores pudo serme de utilidad para resolver el problema pero pude lograrlo de otra manera.

```
$fechaMedido = strtotime($record->size_date);
$fechaConcluida = strtotime('+5 days' . $fechaMedido);
$segundos = $fechaConcluida - $fechaMedido;
$dias = $segundos / 86400;

if($dias < -19390){
    $result = '<span style="background-color:#2FC441; padding:3px; color:white; 
    border-radius: 5px; font-size:14px;">A tiempo</span>';
} elseif ($dias >= -19390){
    $result = '<span style="background-color:#CB4335; padding:3px; color:white; 
    border-radius: 5px; font-size:14px;">Recotizar</span>';
}


return $result;
```

Habiendo restado ambas fechas transformadas en formato Unix y luego dividiendolas por 86400 (la fracción en segundos de un día) logré que funcione.

Abrazo grande a toda esta excelente comunidad!! Gracias por todo

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la principal razón de no obtener los resultados deseados se debe a que estas validando la fechas como cadenas de texto, te sugiero hacerlo con valores numéricos(Fecha Unix).

He realizado algunos ajustes al código adjuntado tratando de explicar cada linea:

```
// $fechaMedicion = $record->size_date;
$fechaMedicion = "01-01-2023";

// obtener el valor de la fecha en fecha Unix 
$fechaMedicionUnix = strtotime($fechaMedicion);

// sumar los 5 dias a la fecha de medición
$tiemposConcluidos = strtotime('+5 days', $fechaMedicionUnix );

$result = "";

// realizar validación utilizando las fechas en formato Unix
if ($fechaMedicionUnix >= $tiemposConcluidos){
        $result = 'A tiempo';
} elseif ($fechaMedicion < $tiemposConcluidos){
        $result = 'Urgente';
}

return $result;
```

Espero haber podido ayudar.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error en el código que provocará que la función siempre devuelva "Urgente". La comparación `if ($fechaMedicion >= $tiemposConcluidos)` debería ser `if (strtotime($fechaMedicion) >= strtotime($tiemposConcluidos))` para comparar las fechas como valores de tiempo en lugar de comparar las cadenas de fecha formateadas. Aquí está el código corregido:

```
$fechaMedicion = $record->size_date;
$tiemposConcluidos = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fechaMedicion. "+ 5 days"));
$result = "";            
    if (strtotime($fechaMedicion) >= strtotime($tiemposConcluidos)) {
           $result = 'A tiempo';
    } elseif (strtotime($fechaMedicion) < strtotime($tiemposConcluidos)) {
           $result = 'Urgente';
    }
return $result;
```